# Remove Tickmarks on Seaborn 0.9.0 Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

After upgrading Seaborn from 0.7.1 to 0.9.0, I am now unable to eliminate tickmarks from my plots.  Here is my attempt using the example provided from Seaborn [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html):

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sinplot(flip=1):
    x = np.linspace(0, 14, 100)
    for i in range(1, 7):
        plt.plot(x, np.sin(x + i * .5) * (7 - i) * flip)

%matplotlib inline
sns.set_style({'xtick.bottom': False,
                'xtick.top': False,
                'ytick.left': False,
                'ytick.right': False})
sinplot()
sns.despine(trim=True)
```

[image]

I'm also wondering why the style looks to matplotlib-y.  How can I remove the tickmarks and make the graph look cleaner?

Comment: works fine for me on `seaborn 0.9.0`

Comment: I'm running `matplotlib 1.5.1`, same for you?

Comment: No, `2.2.2` for me, maybe that's where the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'xtick.bottom'` etc. parameters are no valid rc params for matplotlib 1.5. You could use the `xtick.major.size` parameter, which is available though.

In general, I think while seaborn pretends to be working nicely even with older versions of matplotlib, there are sure cases where using a 3 year old matplotlib version with the newest seaborn version may not in all cases give the best visual result. So I would recommend either using matplotlib 1.5 together with seaborn 0.7, or matplotlib 2.2.3 or higher together with seaborn 0.9.